# WSDL Document generator wsdl-viewer

Tags: web-services, xslt, wsdl

I am looking for a tool to generate documentation from a WSDL file. I have found wsdl-viewer.xsl which seems promissing. See https://code.google.com/p/wsdl-viewer/

However, I am seeing a limitation where references to complex data types are not mapped out (or explained). For example, say we have a createSnapshot() operation that creates a snapshot and returns an object representing an snapshot. Runing xsltproc(1) and using wsdl-viewer.xsl, the rendered documentation has an output section that describes the output as

```
Output: createSnapshotOut 
   parameter type ceateSnapshotResponse
      snapshots type Snapshot
```

I'd like to be able to click on "Snapshot" and see the schema definition of Snapshot.

Is this possible? Perhaps I am not using xsltproc(1) correctly. Perhaps it is not able to find the xsd files. Here are some of the relevant files I have:

```
SnapshotMgmntProvider.wsdl
SnapshotMgmntProviderDefinitions.xsd  
SnapshotMgmntProviderTypes.xsd
```

Thanks
Medi